# Handling null values inside a WHERE with ANY Condition in linq

Tags: c#, linq

My problem is the db object can have a null description and ofc linq will throw Null Exception with ANY. I am using this to search both description and title .

here is the code

```
string[] searchQry = searchString.Split(' ');            
searchQry = searchQry.Select(sq=> sq.ToLower()).ToArray();

searchResult = x.reportsInfo
    .Where(r => 
        searchQry.Any(y => r.report.Description.ToLower().Contains(y)) ||
        searchQry.Any(y => r.report.Title.ToLower().Contains(y)))
    .ToList();
```

tried encapsulating it with ternary conditional operator.

Comment: `ofc` What exact exception was thrown? What SQL was submitted to the database? How large (how many entries) are there usually in `searchQry`? What is the type of `x` and `x.reportsInfo`? Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
 y => r.report.Description?.ToLower().Contains(y) ?? false
```

This uses the null propagation operator (`?`) to avoid `NullReferenceException` in the case of `Description` being `null` and if it's `null` then we use the null coalescing operator (`??`) to provide a default value (`false` in this case).

btw you can merge both the `Any` calls into one:

```
searchQry.Any(r => r.report.Description?.ToLower().Contains(y) ?? false 
                 || r.report.Title.ToLower().Contains(y))
```

if you want to apply the criteria to each and every `Description` first before applying it on `Title` then you'll need to stick with your approach of two individual `Any` calls:

```
.Where(r => searchQry.Any(y => r.report.Description?.ToLower().Contains(y) ?? false)
     ||  searchQry.Any(y => r.report.Title.ToLower().Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Another approach being to use a `Where` clause before `Any` to filter out the records where the `Description` is null:

```
searchResult = x.reportsInfo
                 .Where(r => searchQry.Where(r => r.report.Description != null)
                                      .Any(y => r.report.Description.ToLower().Contains(y))
                     ||searchQry.Any(y => r.report.Title.ToLower().Contains(y)))                                        
                .ToList();
```